# Unable to redirect to another page using javascript while using jquery

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am unable to redirect to another after successful login through my webservice. I am getting correct response from web service But page doesn't redirect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function registerUser() {
        try {
            var username = document.getElementById("UserName");
            var pwd = document.getElementById("Password");
            $.ajax({
                datatype: "json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:51290/CMSWebService.asmx/LoginUser",
                data: "{'username':'" + username.value + "','pwd':'" + pwd.value + "'}",
                async:false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("hello");
                    window.location.replace("default.aspx");// to redirect error occurs here

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    if (data.d) {
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        catch (e) {
            debugger;
            alert(e);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try window.location.replace(" full url of your page ") .

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function registerUser() {
        try {
            var username = document.getElementById("UserName");
            var pwd = document.getElementById("Password");
            $.ajax({
                datatype: "json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:51290/CMSWebService.asmx/LoginUser",
                data: "{'username':'" + username.value + "','pwd':'" + pwd.value + "'}",
                async:false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    window.location = "./default.aspx";
                    alert("hello");

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    if (data.d) {
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        catch (e) {
            debugger;
            alert(e);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Try this